# Expose C# service to C++ COM client

Tags: c#, c++, dll, service, com

I have lot of function calls and back events in an .NET dll.
which I want to expose above as service.
This new service will be consumed by new .Net application and an old COM C++ application.(two way communication since events with data will be fired from service to clients and client will make function call on service)
I know we can use WCF or GRPC to do this.
But WCF is dead and GRPC depends on IDL/Proto file which i want to avoid.
Are there any other possible solutions which are simple.

Comment: It ultimately depends on your context and details but SignalR (wraps WebSockets) is quite nice. It supports .NET Framework, .NET core and also C++ clients: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier i will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even tough SignalR-Client-Cpp suits our need.
After trying out it, we found that its not actively supported and not easy to use on windows.
So ended up into GRPC.